# Sharepoint site unreachable from external network

Tags: 2013, domain, network

I've installed Sharepoint 2013 Foundation on Windows Server 2008 R2.
I've also a domain like (mysite.com) referred to this server and I've created a site collection.

Now I would like to browse my site from a computer external to the LAN and I don't want use VPN.

So, what configuration need sharepoint to be reachable from outside?

PS: I can access to central administration, but when I browse to mysite.com I receive the IIS7.5 welcome message. Trying to access to my SP site I receive a 404 error.

Comment: Have you updated your AAM and DNS correctly ?

Comment: Can you suggest a guide to do that? Sorry but I'm a newbie in server config.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell what is the address to access that sharepoint? Try to ping to that address inside the server by remote desktop and see if it is replying? Record the IP address and try to ping that IP from your extrnl computer and see if it is also replying?

If it replies, DNS problem there in your computer. If not, that means connection problem.